# display error message immediately when there are multiple if statements. my program displays error message after both are entered

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

if the user enters an invalid weight or age the program is supposed to display an error message immediately and end the program. my program displays an error message after both the age and weight are entered. can anyone help me? example: user enters 1 for the switch statement to choose to enter the age in months and weight in kg. if the user enters -5 for the months it should display error message right away and end the program. instead what my program does is after the -5 has been entered for the age it will prompt the user to then enter the weight. after the weight is entered it then gives me the error message and ends my program. any help will be much appreciated.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;
 public class infant{

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
double ageMonths = 0;
double ageYears = 0;
double weightPounds = 0;
double weightKg = 0;


System.out.println( "Choice 1 input the age in months, then weight in kilograms");          // this tells the user what the numbers 1-4 does when chosen
System.out.println( "Choice 2 input the age in years, weight in kilograms");
System.out.println( "Choice 3 input the age in months, weight in pounds");
System.out.println( "Choice 4 input the age in years, weight in pounds");


number =sc.nextInt();

if(number<=4 && number>=1){                                                  // if statement that makes the user enter a value from 1 to 4 for the switch statment.
        System.out.println("valid number selection");
    }else{ System.out.println("need to choose a number between 1 and 4");
        return;
    }

 switch(number){                                                                    // switch statment that allows the user to choose how they want to enter the height and weight 
    case 1: System.out.println("age in months: ");  ageMonths =sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("weight in kilograms: "); weightKg =sc.nextDouble();
            ageYears = ageMonths * 0.0833334;                                          // this switch statment also converts Kg to pounds and years to months in order for math equation in the if statement at then end of the program to work. 
            weightPounds = weightKg * 2.20462; 
            break;
    case 2: System.out.println("age in years: "); ageYears =sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("weight in kilograms: "); weightKg =sc.nextDouble();
            ageMonths = ageYears * 12; 
            weightPounds = weightKg * 2.20462; 
            break;
    case 3: System.out.println("age in months: "); ageMonths =sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("weight in pounds: "); weightPounds =sc.nextDouble();
            ageYears = ageMonths * 0.0833334;
            weightKg = weightPounds * 0.453592;
            break;
    case 4: System.out.println("age in years: "); ageYears =sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("weight in pounds: "); weightPounds =sc.nextDouble();
            ageMonths = ageYears * 12; 
            weightKg = weightPounds * 0.453592; 
            break;
    default: System.out.println("you entered in an invalid number"); 

}    

 if(ageMonths<=24 && ageMonths>-0.1){                                        // if statement that makes sure the ages are in the correct range
     System.out.println("valid age input");
    }else if(ageYears>-0.1 && ageYears<=2){
        System.out.println("valid age input");
    }else{ System.out.println("You entered a invaild age 0 to 24 months only");
        return;
}

    if(weightPounds>=4.40925 && weightPounds<=33.0693 || weightKg>=2 && weightKg<=15){      // if statement that makes sure the weight are in the correct range
        System.out.println("valid weight input");
    }else{ System.out.println("You entered a invaild weight 2kg to 15kg only");
        return;
    }




    if(weightKg >= ageYears * ageMonths / 3 + 2 && weightKg <= 5 * ageYears * ageMonths / 12 + 5){ // if statement that does a math equation to determine if your infant is healthy or not
        System.out.println(" your infant is healthy");
    }else{ System.out.println(" your infant is not healthy");
    }

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for checking the weights and months, you keep the code for both in some different functions and then inside the switch case after you have entered the months, then call the function with that month entered and then you can do the same thing for the weights, this way you can have a structure you want.. Do ask if you need any kind of clarification.

```
function checkMonths(double ageMonths){
if(ageMonths<=24 && ageMonths>-0.1){                                        // if statement that makes sure the ages are in the correct range
 System.out.println("valid age input");
}else{ System.out.println("You entered a invaild age 0 to 24 months only");
    return;
}
}
function checkYears(double ageYears){
if(ageYears>-0.1 && ageYears<=2){
    System.out.println("valid age input");
}else{ System.out.println("You entered a invaild age 0 to 24 months only");
    return;
}
}


function checkWeights(double weightPounds){

if(weightPounds>=4.40925 && weightPounds<=33.0693 || weightKg>=2 && weightKg<=15){      // if statement that makes sure the weight are in the correct range
    System.out.println("valid weight input");
}else{ System.out.println("You entered a invaild weight 2kg to 15kg only");
    return;
}

 }
```

Do change the variable names inside the function argument according to your usage.

Comment: so basically what your saying is that I need to have my if statements for the weight and age inside of my switch statement?

Comment: Yeah basically it's that. But you dont need to copy the checking part in all the cases, for that you can form a function.

Comment: I tried to use the code function checkWeights(double weight){

Comment: So what happened??

Comment: but it will not compile

Comment: that is correct. I even changed my import java.util.scanner to java.util.*... still didnt work

Comment: What I meant was you could use this approach, now I have changed the code so that you can use that as its ofcourse pay attention to the normal function declarations and where you want the months you can call this function(1st) otherwise the second one. it would work... pay attention to the approach..

Comment: still does not work.  thanks for the help tho when i type in

Comment: function checkMonths(double ageMonths){ it gives me an complieing error  ; unexpected

Comment: i meant ; expected

Comment: What is the return type of the functions that you have used above?

Comment: it should be a double

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just end your program with invalid input, you could always use System.exit(0) instead of "return." That's guaranteed to end the program.

for instance:

```
 if(number<=4 && number>=1){                                                  // if statement that makes the user enter a value from 1 to 4 for the switch statment.
    System.out.println("valid number selection");
}else{ System.out.println("need to choose a number between 1 and 4");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken, that should terminate the main thread immediately after the print statement.